# Is it possible to use the PlayStation's media player as a standalone program on PC?

Tags: linux, emulation, multimedia, playstation, app

I'd like to use the PlayStation media player (the one with SoundScope) on a modern operating system (GNU/Linux) instead of the default player.

Is it possible?

Note: this Q&A has been moved from [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25757/is-it-possible-to-use-the-playstations-media-player-as-a-standalone-program-on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check `soundscope-player` ([source](https://github.com/tallero/soundscope-player), [`AUR`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/soundscope-player)).

It's a Python program that creates audio CDR (`.bin` + `.cue`) images on the fly (using `mkaudiocdrimg`, a little python wrapper for `shntool` I also wrote) from input files and feeds them to `duckstation`.

It uses `GtkFileChooserDialog` for handling opening a media source when launching the program from the overview.

Unless through AUR, you need to provide a PlayStation bios manually to run the application correctly.

It can be easily built on Windows using `msys2`+`mingw`, since the AUR recipe is easily adapted.